# Is the grappling strike maneuver a part of an attack or used after the hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter

Battlemaster says

> Maneuvers. You learn three maneuvers of your choice, which are listed under "Maneuvers" below. Many maneuvers enhance an attack in some way. **You can use only one maneuver per attack.**

but unlike other maneuvers, grappling strike uses "immediately after you hit" instead of "when you hit," with that wording it might be a maneuver that the character can execute after achieving the necessary setup (hitting with a melee attack and having a bonus action available), rather than a part of the attack itself.

Is grappling strike limited to the one maneuver per attack clause?

Comment: I don't understand the distinction that you are seeing or making.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grappling strike is still tied to one specific attack that is made and it's part of that attack.

The attack had not yet been resolved because hitting is not the end of the attack process:

> **3. Resolve the attack**. You make the attack roll. On a hit, you roll damage, unless the particular attack has rules that specify otherwise. Some attacks cause special effects in addition to or instead of damage.

Grappling Attack attaches an additional rider effect onto the attack. It happens after the *hit*, not after the *attack* so you are still using one maneuver per that attack.